# Write dates to Excel properly from R

Tags: r

When I write dataframe to the file it considers all columns as characters including the date column.

```
options(xlsx.date.format = "yyyy-mm-dd")
write.xlsx(data, excel_filename, sheetName = "Data")
```

[image]

How can I write data to xlsx file such that when I work with this column it considered as date by default?

**Solution:** Turns the class of the column was character. After conversion with `as.Date` everything is saved properly.

Comment: Should it instead be [`options(openxlsx.dateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd")`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/vignettes/formatting.pdf)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295571/how-to-prevent-write-csv-from-changing-posixct-dates-and-times-class-back-to-ch , does this help ?

Comment: @r2evans didn't work :(

Comment: @Sathish, Tried that too, but didn't work

Comment: @user5249203 do you mean it's possible to force excel to read it as date?

Comment: Were you able to follow the vignette pointed to in my last comment? It talks specifically about transferring dates to excel (pages 3-4).

Comment: @SergeyIvanov : `write.xlsx(data.frame(seq(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date() + 2, "days")), "myfile.xlsx", sheetName = "Data", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)`

Comment: @r2evans I tried it, but it's still the same

Comment: @Sathish's comment worked for me, inserting a field that Excel sees as "Date" format. Are you certain the values in `data` are actually `POSIX*` and not `character`?

Comment: @Sathish, I'm not sure if I was explicit enough, but what I need is excel considering the column as date such that I can sort from oldest to newest, not from A to Z. I don't try the string to be in a format "YYYY-MM-DD", I already have it.

Comment: check if your date column in R dataframe has `class  = "Date"` in it. For example, `class(Sys.Date())`

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, I was looking at `openxlsx` (happened to be loaded for my current work).

Comment: Thanks everyone, turns out in `data` indeed the dates were having class character (didn't know it, since I was getting from the database query). After conversion to as.Date(), everything works properly. Kudos to everyone!

Answer (score 3):

You may try using `lubridate` or `chron` libraries for this task. However, I do not think your issue is coming from R but more with how excel is reading it. In your question, is the image you show of how you want it to look or how it currently looks? In any case, when using chron for example, you can say

```
 format.Date(dates, "%Y/%m/%d")
```

Answer (score 3):

The reference manual for `xlsx` explains it very clearly with example. Below is a slight modified Source: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/xlsx.pdf
I think, you were following the same approach. working with workbook saves the format of the date.

```
wb <- createWorkbook(type="xlsx")
 sheet <- createSheet(wb, sheetName="addDataFrame1")
 data <- data.frame(date=seq(as.Date("1999-01-01"), by="1 year", length.out=10))
 addDataFrame(data, sheet, startRow = 1, startColumn=1)
 # to change the default date format use something like this
 options(xlsx.date.format="dd MMM, yyyy")
 # Don't forget to save the workbook ...
 saveWorkbook(wb, "Path/test.xlsx") # your path to the excel sheet
```