# Convert character format to date, gives me as "unknown" result, what do I do?

Tags: r, date, format

I have to export a table, with columns of text, and 3 columns with the date type.
But I can't convert the date columns to date.
They are originally in "character" format.
The data frame is as follows:

Fecha de ejecucion

2022-05-31

2022-05-31

2022-05-31

2022-05-31

I want to move on to date with the formula:

```
BtotalSinPublico$’Fecha de ejecucion’ <- as.Date(BtotalSinPublico$’Fecha de ejecucion’)
```

The query: `Class(BtotalSinPublico$’Fecha de ejecucion’)`
It results in: [1] Date

But when I stand in the column of the data frame it enunciates the format 'unknown'.  And when I export it:

```
WriteXLS(BtotalSinPublico, ExcelFileName = str_c("PrevisionesNiif_",Fecha,".xls)
```

The columns are formatted in General.

Comment: Dates are *stored* as a number but can be *presented* in a nice date format.  You will probably want to replace `Fecha` in the document name with `format(Fecha, xxx)` where `xxx` is the date format you want.  See this [help page](https://r-lang.com/r-date-format/) for info on formatting dates and this chapter of the [r4ds book](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/dates-and-times.html) for more info.

Comment: + You might want to use another package to get the date formatting in excel. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960571/write-dates-to-excel-properly-from-r

Comment: test the following code -> 
BtotalSinPublico$`Fecha de ejecucion` <- Sys.Date()
BtotalSinPublico$`Fecha de ejecucion` <- format(BtotalSinPublico$`Fecha de ejecucion`, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
and returns the "character" format as a result.

Comment: poor all these codes and none worked: 
BtotalSinPublico$`Fecha de ejecucion` <- as.POSIXct(BtotalSinPublico$`Fecha de ejecucion`, format  = '%Y-%m-%d')

BtotalSinPublico$`Fecha de ejecucion` <- as.Date('2022-05-31', format   = '%Y-%m-%d')
BtotalSinPublico$`Fecha de ejecucion` <- anytime(BtotalSinPublico$`Fecha de ejecucion`)
BtotalSinPublico$`Fecha de ejecucion` <- Sys.Date()
BtotalSinPublico$`Fecha de ejecucion` <- format(BtotalSinPublico$`Fecha de ejecucion`, format = "%Y-%m-%d")